# Empty reply from Django web service

Tags: python, django, apache, unity-game-engine

I have created a web service in django  and its hosted on a shared server.The django web service respond to request from a game made in [**unity**](http://unity3d.com/). But whenever game tries to request a django Web service url the server send empty resonse.Response is always:

***WWW Error: server return empty string***

The Unity webplayer expects a http served policy file named "crossdomain.xml" to be available on the domain you want to access with the WWW class, (although this is not needed if it is the same domain that is hosting the unity3d file).So I placed a file "crossdomain.xml" at the root of my domain ,but still i am getting same empty reply.Help plz...

**EDIT:**
I tried it through browser my service works fine and reply with proper response.And you know what My game can communicate to django web service when both are running on local machine.But now the django project is hosted on actual server and when game tried accessing service it never get response :(

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^crossdomain.xml$',views.CrossDomain),                   
    url(r'^ReadFile/$',views.ReadFile),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def CrossDomain(request):
    f = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'jsondata/crossdomain.xml', 'r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/xml")

def ReadFile(request):
   f = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'jsondata/some_file.json', 'r')
   data = f.read()
   f.close()
   return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/javascript")

def Test(request):
   return HttpResponse("Hello", mimetype="text/plain")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said using django for this is slight overkill because you could just serve them. Point aside though. If your serving on a different server it could be

A) Connection problems mean that your response is lost
B) Firewall issues mean that the request mean something
C) The server isn't setup correctly and therefore it justs get an error.

You need to test the response on the server. so is you access the page on the server through your browser. If so then make the game make a request and check the server error and access logs. In the apache access log you should see something like

GET "/url" 200 each time a request is made.

If you don't see any request getting through then either the request isn't made or its been lost.
If you do then the problem is in the code somewhere.